# Complex multiplication over p adic fields

Tags: field-theory, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Elliptic curve $E$ over a field $K$ is said to have complex multiplication if $E$ has endomorphism except for multiplication by $n$($n∈\Bbb{Z}$) maps.

We usually consider $K$ as $ \Bbb{C}$.In this case, elliptic curve which has completely multiplication is very rare.

My question is,
what happen in the case $K＝$(p-adic field) ?
Here, p-adic field means finite extension of $ \Bbb{Q}_p$. For example, let $p$ be an odd prime, $E:y^2＝x^3-x$, ($x,y$)→($-x, \sqrt{-1}y$)(notice $\sqrt{-1}∈\Bbb{Q}_p$), so it has complex multiplication.
But are elliptic curves over such fields are rare ?
Although definition of 'rare' is ambiguous, if you know some thing to remark, I appreciated if you could hear some remarks.

Comment: Morally complex or $p$-adic field don't make much difference as in characteristic $0$ an algebraic variety is defined over a field $L$ which is a finitely generated extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ so $L$ embeds both in $\Bbb{C}$ and $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$. The $j$-invariant of CM elliptic curves are algebraic integers, this is enough to make them very rare over $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$.